# From where does V8 or Libuv process my index.js in Nodejs source code

Tags: node.js

I want to see how and where V8 parse or compile my index.js in NodeJS source code.
These are what I found

1. `main(int argc, char* argv[])` [node_main.cc]
2. `node::Start(argc, argv)` [node_main.cc - main()]
3. `int Start(int argc, char** argv)` [node.cc]
4. `V8::Initialize()` [node.cc - Start()]. but dont pass the argv argument. This may mean that V8 does not process our index.js in here( Am I right? )
5. `Start(uv_default_loop(), args, exec_args)` [node.cc - Start()]
6. `Start(isolate, isolate_data.get(), args, exec_args)` [node.cc - `inline int Start(uv_loop_t* event_loop, const std::vector<std::string>& args, const std::vector<std::string>& exec_args) {`]. I'm following the exec_args argument. And there are many Start() function in node.cc OTL...
7. `env.Start(args, exec_args, v8_is_profiling)` [node.cc - `inline int Start(Isolate* isolate, IsolateData* isolate_data, const std::vector<std::string>& args, const std::vector<std::string>& exec_args) {`]. I thought that my index.js may be processed in that env.start() function.
8. `SetupProcessObject(this, args, exec_args)` [env.cc - `Environment::Start(const std::vector<std::string>& args, const std::vector<std::string>& exec_args, bool start_profiler_idle_notifier)`]

I stopped here. I can't find where V8 process my index.js.

Please show me some light.

Comment: Where did you get this? How is your index.js like, are you requiring any libs, etc?

Comment: I found this from https://github.com/nodejs/node. What I want to know just, Where does V8 process(parse, compile) my index.js codes in that NodeJS Open Source.